# Parse.com ParseQuery inconstancy

Tags: android, parse-platform

I have a very weird situation.  I have an application where I am implementing a "Notification History".

I have a separate application that sends push notifications to targeted channels and then creates an entry into a table called Notifications, saving the channel that was targeted and the message that was sent.

```
channels = channelEditText.getText().toString();
                message = messageEditText.getText().toString();
                ParsePush push = new ParsePush();
                push.setChannel(channels);
                push.setMessage(message);
                push.sendInBackground();
                channelEditText.setText("");
                messageEditText.setText("");

                ParseObject notifications = new ParseObject("Notifications");
                notifications.add("channels", channels);
                notifications.put("msg", message);
                notifications.saveInBackground();
```

My Android app's "Notification History" fragment then performs

```
ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject> notificationAdapter =
            new ParseQueryAdapter<ParseObject>(getActivity(), new ParseQueryAdapter.QueryFactory<ParseObject>() {
                public ParseQuery<ParseObject> create() {
                    ParseQuery query = new ParseQuery("Notifications");
                    query.whereContainedIn("channels", ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getList("channels"));
                    query.orderByDescending("createdAt");
                    return query;
                }
            });
        notificationAdapter.setTextKey("msg");
        ListView notificationListView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.notificationListView);
        notificationListView.setAdapter(notificationAdapter);
```

My ParseApplication.java subscribes a user to channel: "Welcome" on installation so I don't receive a null pointer. The Notifications Table entry with channel "Welcome" populates the listview.

I have two ways to subscribe to a channel.  One way is on the device itself like this

```
final EditText syncInput = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.syncInput);
        Button syncButton = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.syncButton);

        syncButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            public void onClick(View v){

                String sync = null;
                sync = syncInput.getText().toString();
                PushService.subscribe(getActivity(), sync, DashboardActivity.class);
                syncInput.setText("");
            }

        });
```

The other way is through CloudCode

```
Parse.Cloud.define("subscribeToChannel", function(request, response){
var channelName = request.params.channel;
var userId = request.params.userId;

if(!channelName) {
    response.error("Missing parameter: channel");
    return;
}

if (!userId) {
    response.error("Missing paremeter: userId");
    return;
}

//Create a Pointer to the user based on their object id
var user = new Parse.User();
user.id = userId;

Parse.Cloud.useMasterKey();

// A user might have more than one installation
var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
query.equalTo("user", user); //Match Installations with a pointer to this User
query.find({
    success: function(installations) {
        for (var i = 0; i < installations.length; i++) {
            //Add the channel to al the installations for this user
            installations[i].addUnique("channels", channelName);
        }

        //Save all the installations
        Parse.Object.saveAll(installations, {
            success: function(installations) {
                //All the installations where saved.
                response.success("All the installations were updated with this channel.");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                //An error occured while saving one of the objects.
                console.error(error);
                response.error("An error occured while updating this user's installations.");
            }
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {
        console.error(error);
        response.error("An error occurred while looking up this user's installations");
    }
});
```

});

Both ways of subscribing are successful in that a Push notification sent to the target channel reaches the device. Here is the issue...  If I use the device to subscribe my query will show the messages sent to that channel that is saved in the Notifications table.  If I use the CloudCode my query does NOT show the message sent to the channel that is saved in the Notification table.

I'm stumped.  Any help is deeply appreciated.

--------------------------------SOLUTION-------------------------------------------------

```
protected void onResume() {
     super.onResume();
    ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().refreshInBackground(new RefreshCallback(){

        @Override
        public void done(ParseObject parseObject, ParseException e) {
             List<String> channels = ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().getList("channels");
                for (int i = 0; i < channels.size(); i++) {
                    Log.w("TEST", channels.get(i));

        }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're editing the Installation record on the server-side in Cloud Code, but the device isn't getting the updated data.  If this is a common behavior in your app, refresh the installation object when you load the app:

```
ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().refreshInBackground();
```

or fetchInBackground, as shown here: https://parse.com/docs/android_guide#objects-retrieving

This could also be solved by, instead of querying from the device, calling a cloud function which does the query (with the updated channels list already on the server-side.)

Comment: I used this  ParseInstallation.getCurrentInstallation().refreshInBackground();
but error getting refreshInBackground is deprecated, is there any other solution?